# Java heap dump (hprof file) is much smaller that resident memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

When running top is see my `RES` is 4.7GB, which is fine, since I set `-Xmx8g`, but when I dump it to hprof file, I get about half a gig file.

Isn't is suppose to contain all memory ?
By the way, even if I force GC (using jcmd) I still see 4.7G resident.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666667/heapdump-size-vs-hprof-size

Comment: I think my problem is the other way around. my hprof is also small, not containing all objects. anyhow, after running `GC.run` it should of free resident memory, no ?

Comment: The explanation for that would take longer than 600 characters, so to keep it short: not necessarily. You can try some of the methods they explain in the answers but if they don't work i don't know what to tell you (maybe amazing compression? :))

Comment: You can try in a reply...  Is there a way I can get all the 4.7 gigs resident?

Comment: Another short answer: It won't always force GC to run if you call it, you might want to do a little research on that matter. To get all 4.7 gigs I recommend you try to use visualvm or eclipse/jmap. These options usually given you an option to dump all the invalid references (basically the "garbage" that is supposed to be collected but you still want)

Comment: The missing memory isn't allocated to Java objects, so it isn't dumped. It is free space in the heap.

Comment: @EJP - Thats what i thought, so why isn't being free on `GC.run` ?

Answer (score 1):

Heap dump file (hprof) is not a memory dump, but object heap dump. It contains only java objects.

Heap dump file does not include
- non-heap arreas of memory (e.g. code cache, metaspace, etc)
- some heap objects (e.g. classes) are not included in dump
- free regions reserved but not used in heap

In your case, you probably have a lot of unused heap space.
GC does not return used space to OS, so RES size remain 4.7G